# Do Rust macros work inside trait definitions?

Tags: rust

I can build structs and enums using macros but not traits. Is this a bug or something about how traits work that I am missing? Here is a simple example that fails to build:

```
macro_rules! fun{
  () => { fn hello(); }
}

macro_rules! full_fun{
  () => { fn hello(){} }
}

// Fails with:
// <anon>:13:8: 13:11 error: expected one of `const`, `extern`, `fn`, `type`, or `unsafe`, found `fun`
// <anon>:13        fun!();
macro_rules! trait_macro{
  ($name:ident) => {
     pub trait $name {
       fun!();
     }
 }; 
}

macro_rules! struct_macro{
  ($name:ident) => {
     pub struct $name;

     impl $name {
       full_fun!();
     }
 };
}

// I can add functions to a Impl
struct_macro!{Monster}
// But I cannot add functions to a trait
trait_macro!{Monster}


fn main() {

}
```

Comment: This has now been implemented see [Issue34183](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/34183)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Macro inside trait expansion is currently not supported. The relevant AST code:

```
pub enum TraitItemKind {
    Const(P<Ty>, Option<P<Expr>>),
    Method(MethodSig, Option<P<Block>>),
    Type(TyParamBounds, Option<P<Ty>>),
}
```

As the error message states only one of `const`, `extern`, `fn`, `type`, or `unsafe` are expected as next token in a Trait.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the Rust documentation on macros](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/macros.html), a macro can be expanded as:

- zero or more items
- zero or more methods,
- an expression,
- a statement, or
- a pattern.

Your `full_fun` becomes a method, but I think a declaration inside a trait doesn't count.  (I haven't found an exact reference, though).

Even if it were, it wouldn't help: due to the macro hygiene rules, the `hello` defined couldn't be referenced elsewhere, as it would effectively be a unique identifier different from any other - ie your `fun!()` macro would not be declaring the same function as is implemented by `full_fun!()`.

Comment: Dont worry about the `full_fun!()` its just there to show I can create function items and use them to populate impl for structs - I'm not trying to implement the trait. My `fun!()` macro also expands to an item. So it should be ok to used inside a trait